# Why is JMP ESP required in buffer overflow?

Tags: disassembly, windows, assembly, buffer-overflow, esp

I was reading [this](https://vulp3cula.gitbook.io/hackers-grimoire/exploitation/buffer-overflow) article by Hackers Grimoire on Windows buffer overflow attacks.

The article made sense, except for the part where the author searched for a DLL (.dll) file which contained a `JMP ESP` instruction. I understood the other requirements, such as ensuring the DLL was not protected with DEP, ASLR etc...

Why was it necessary to find a DLL file with `JMP ESP` and note its memory address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the instruction pointer will always follow the program flow, unless you can alter it. They key time to alter it is on the return from a function, when the saved instruction pointer is popped off the stack into `eip`. If you can overwrite the saved instruction pointer you can redirect program execution.

Finding a `jmp esp` at a semi-predictable place in memory allows you to redirect execution to the top of the stack reliably.

So the process would be something like:

- Overwrite saved instruction pointer (ebp+4) on the stack with the address of `jmp esp` in the .dll.
- When the function returns, execution continues at the `jmp esp` instruction.
- The `jmp esp` then redirects execution to the top of the stack where your payload is waiting.